# .sheet in SwiftUI strange behaviour when passing a variable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using .sheet view in SwiftUI and I am observing a strange behavior in the execution of the code.

I am having a view SignInView2:

```
 struct SignInView2: View {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@State var invitationUrl = URL(string: "www")
@State private var showingSheet = false


var body: some View {
    VStack {
    Text("Share Screen")
        
        Button(action: {
            print("link: \(invitationUrl)") // Here I see the new value assigned from createLink() 
            self.showingSheet = true
        }) {
            Text("Share")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
        let invitationLink = invitationUrl?.absoluteString  // Paasing the old value (www)
        ActivityView(activityItems: [NSURL(string: invitationLink!)] as [Any], applicationActivities: nil)
    }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        createLink()
    }
  }
}
```

which calls create a link method when it appears:

```
extension SignInView2 {

func createLink()  {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        print("tuk0")
            return }

    let link = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/?invitedby=\(uid)")
    print("tuk1:\(String(describing: link))")
    let referralLink = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link!, domainURIPrefix: "https://makeitso.page.link")
    print("tuk2:\(String(describing: referralLink))")
    referralLink?.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "com.IVANDOS.ToDoFirebase")
    referralLink?.iOSParameters?.minimumAppVersion = "1.0"
    referralLink?.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "13129650"

    referralLink?.shorten { (shortURL, warnings, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
      }
        print("tuk4: \(shortURL)")
        self.invitationUrl = shortURL!
    }
  }
}
```

That method assigns a value to the **invitationUrl** variable, which is passed to the sheet. Unfortunatelly, when the sheet appears, I don't see the newly assigned variable but I see only "www". Can you explain me how to pass the new value generated from createLink()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known behaviour of `sheet` since SwiftUI 2.0. Content is created in time of sheet created not in time of showing. So the solution can be either to use `.sheet(item:...` modifier or passing binding in sheet content view (which is kind of reference to state storage and don't need to be updated).

Here is a demo of possible approach. Prepared with Xcode 12.4.

```
struct SignInView2: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var invitationUrl: URL?     // by default is absent

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Share Screen")
            
            Button(action: {
                print("link: \(invitationUrl)")
                self.invitationUrl = createLink()   // assignment activates sheet
            }) {
                Text("Share")
            }
            .sheet(item: $invitationUrl) {
                ActivityView(activityItems: [$0] as [Any], applicationActivities: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Needed to be used as sheet item
extension URL: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self.absoluteString }
}
```